# ' ValueError: to_quantize can only either be a tf.keras Sequential or Functional model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I've tried QAT implementation in my model training script. I'm using functional API for the model creation.

Steps that I followed to implement QAT API,

1. Build the model acrhitecture
2. Inserted the appropriate quantize_model function
3. Train the model

Let me provide you the code snippet for more clearance

```
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed,SeparableConv1D,Dense,Embedding,Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dropout, MaxPooling1D,Flatten, concatenate, BatchNormalization, AveragePooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Progbar
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import non_neg , min_max_norm, max_norm , unit_norm
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.quantization.keras import quantize


 words_input = Input(shape=(None,),dtype='int32',name='words_input')
 words = Embedding(input_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[0], output_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[1],  weights=[wordEmbeddings], trainable=False)(words_input)    
 ............
 convd_output= SeparableConv1D(kernel_size=4, filters=128, padding='same', activation='relu', strides=1, depth_multiplier=3, bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001), kernel_constraint =min_max_norm(0.4,0.9))(output)

 convd_output=AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1, padding='same')(convd_output)
 convd_output=Dropout(0.1)(convd_output)      
 flatten_output=TimeDistributed(Flatten())(convd_output)          
 
 output = TimeDistributed(Dense(len(label2Idx), activation='softmax'))(flatten_output)

 inputs_list=[words_input, casing_input,newline_input]
 model = Model(*inputs_list, output)
 q_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model(model)
 opt = Nadam(lr=0.0005)       
 q_aware_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
 print(q_aware_model.summary())
```

**Version details**

> tensorflow==2.3.0

> tensorflow-model-optimization==0.5.0

**Issue :** I'm using functional API which is supported in QAT API, but still I'm getting a value error

> quantize_model 'to_quantize can only either be a tf.keras Sequential
> or ValueError: to_quantize can only either be a tf.keras Sequential or
> Functional model.

Couldn't able to figure out the issue. It will be helpful if someone help to get over this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add imports to your question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I've added the imports

Comment: Without seeing you full model, it is hard to debug -- it is possible that one of you inputs is not a keras layers input layer or you have some non-keras tensor handling in your graph definition. Try printing out the property `model._is_graph_network` immediately after initializing the model. If it is true, then there is a bug in TFMOT here.